# rotating the screen with boot args

Tags: embedded

I have an embedded linux system which doesn't run a display server/compositor. Instead I run apps through drm/gbm/opengl. One of the issues however is that the screen is upside down in some configurations.
Now I can make a seperate dtb for these configurations where I add `rotation = <180>;` to the panel node, but I found [this](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/dri-devel/patch/2afd45902d7e1e849d0aa7a0c4268c424cabe778.1554988934.git-series.maxime.ripard@bootlin.com/) bit of kernel code.

This seems to suggest I should be able to do this with a boot argument/parameter, but I can't find any [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) of what this boot argument should be.
I can see a 'rotate' and '=' token being looked for in the code, but I tried many combinations, and none of them seemed to work.

Is it actually possible to do this with boot args? Or should I just take the less comfortable route and make a separate dtb?